# Eliminating endpoints and writing a loop

Tags: python

I have data files that I am analyzing which are arranged in 3 columns of various lengths. I am performing a few calculations and also plotting the results. Here is an example of one such file:

```
-0.295  114.25439   150.5044481
-0.245  98.9089867  131.2786312
-0.195  86.11390819 116.4532951
-0.145  71.14000831 94.24134187
-0.095  58.13286891 76.8665462
-0.045  45.72259815 67.27844179
0.005   33.47819577 58.80690751
0.055   28.07752973 49.65840815
0.105   31.59224024 47.15886962
0.155   41.13397688 49.31988308
0.205   53.87164452 53.27500472
0.255   64.64565747 61.04637756
0.305   73.67569745 71.56437772
```

I am applying a 2nd order polynomial fit to this data (after I've performed some calculations). The 2nd and 3rd column I multiply by a constant, square it, and then I plot this vs. the 1st column.

My problem is that the polyfit doesn't pass through the minimum in col's 2 and 3 (or col's 1 and 2 in Python speak) and so I would like to eliminate some data points to make the fit better and get it to pass through the minimum in col's 2 and 3.

How can I start by just eliminating the endpoints? For example, just the first row and last row. And is there a way to do this without having to define what the endpoints are? I'd like this to be generic so that I can load any file without having to change the code.

Follow-up question: Is it possible to write a loop that would eliminate the first set of endpoints, run my calculation, then the second set of endpoints, and so on...?

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
L = np.loadtxt('filename.txt')


P = float(raw_input("Beam Energy (MeV) ="))
S12 = float(raw_input("Drift Length (m)="))


k = ((L[:, 0]) * 10.135 * 40.0) / (P * 1.8205)
SigmaX = 9.4 * pow(10, -6) * L[:, 1]
SigmaY = 9.4 * pow(10, -6) * L[:, 2]


SigmaX2 = SigmaX**2
SigmaY2 = SigmaY**2
```

Comment: To be clear, are you asking to remove the first and last line from the data? If so, the parts of your code that look like L[:, x] should be changed to use the start and end indices (L[:] means L[0:l.shape(0)] so you can just manipulate that directly)

Comment: Yes Ned. I was originally doing this in Excel just to get some quick results, but my end goal is to do this in Python. In Excel, if I eliminated a few of the data points at the ends then the fit would pass through the minimum, so I'd like to try that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try every symmetrical set of endpoints, you can use a loop like this (along with the slicing suggestion):

```
L = np.loadtxt('test.txt')
trimmedL = L

while len(trimmedL) > 0:
     trimmedL = trimmedL[1:-1,]
     do_calculations(trimmedL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first and last row by using the slice operator in python.

Example data:

```
1 5 9
2 6 0
3 7 1
4 8 2
```

code:

```
var data = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5,6,7,8],[9, 0, 1, 2]]
new_data = data[:][1:-1] # get everything from 2nd row upto (not including) the last row
print new_data
```

output:

```
[[2,3],[6,7],[0,1]]
```

As to weather or not this is the best way to reject data to make your data fit the minimums in column 2 and 3 of your data. I don't know.